# Run Webpack plugin only with flag

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin

i have some plugin in my Webpack config:

```
plugins: [
    new somePlugin()
]
```

But i want does not start this plugin when i just run `npm run start`, but run if i add some flags, like `npm run start --plugin` for example. Is it possible to implement this without dividing the Webpack into different configurations?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by passing env variables with the webpack command

For Reference read this https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#environment-options

run => webpack --env.production

Change the module.exports in webpack.config.js as this

```
module.exports = function(env, argv) {
  return {
    mode: env.production ? 'production' : 'development',
    devtool: env.production ? 'source-maps' : 'eval',
     plugins: [
       new TerserPlugin({
         terserOptions: {
          compress: argv['optimize-minimize'] // only if -p or --optimize-minimize were passed
         }
       })
     ]
  };
};
```

Pass any env variable and use it to conditionally push plugins in your config.